# Null values provoke errors on my Basic Column chart

Tags: php, highcharts

I am using the basic column Highcharts, it work fine until

1- I have **all** the values are null then I have the error  : **Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13**
(for me I can have null value introduced)

**Update ----the whole error:**

[image]

2-When I have **some** values are null , I dont want to display them on the chart :
[image]

my code :

```
public function myChartBasicColumn($date, $list1, $list2)
{
    $sellsHistory = array(
        $list1,
        $list2,

    );

    $dates = $date;

    $ob = new Highchart();
    // ID de l'élement de DOM que vous utilisez comme conteneur
    $ob->chart->renderTo('myChart');

    $ob->title->text('<span style="color:#0068BA"> myChart </span>');
    $ob->chart->type('column');
    $ob->plotOptions->column(
        array(
            'dataLabels' => array(
                'enabled' => true,

            )



        )
    );
    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text' => " myChart "));

    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text' => ""));
    $ob->xAxis->categories($dates);

    $ob->series($sellsHistory);

    return $ob;
}

$list1= array(
    'name' => 'Global',
    'type'  => 'column',
    'color' => '#4572A7',

    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'data' => $data1
);


$list2 =  array(
    'name' => 'Ressource',
    'type'  => 'column',
    'color' => '#D49EDA',
    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'data' => $data2
);

$column = $chart->myChartBasicColumn($date, $list1, $list2);
$html =  $this->render('AdminBundle:admin:chart.html.twig',array(
    'en' =>$en,
    'myChart' => $column,

))->getContent();
```

Comment: 1. I cannot reproduce the error with all null values. Which version of Highcharts do you use? 2. If you do not want to show the column with null values, then you need to preprocess your data (check for nulls) and build the correct series objects without the categories you dont need. You can also use breaks options to hide existing categories - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: I am using Highcharts1.5

Comment: Do you mean Highcharts 5 or is it the php wrapper version? With HC5 it works without errors http://jsfiddle.net/tdt3sjcp/. It might be the problem with how the php wrapper parses data.

Comment: I am using ob/highcharts-bundle 1.5